# DataGridView автоматическое определение ширины столбцов

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли возможность при загрузке данных на `DataGridView` автоматически определять размер столбцов/строк? 
Чтобы не требовался двойной клик, для растягивания шапок столбцов например.

Небольшой листинг для примера:

```
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = list[i].Id.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = list[i].name_st.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = list[i].EnParam.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = list[i].RuParam.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = list[i].UpperLimit.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = list[i].LowerLimit.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```